# Hilt issue with provide class to viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I can't launch my application because of these two new modules `DataStoreModule` and `UserModule`what I have done so far:

```
interface DataStoresProvider {
    fun userDataStore(): DataStore<Preferences>
}
```

```
class UserDataStore(
    dataStoresProvider: DataStoresProvider
) : ModelDataStore<UserModel>(
    dataStoresProvider.userDataStore(),
    USER_KEY
) {
```

```
interface UserRepository {

    suspend fun saveUser(userModel: UserModel)

    suspend fun getUser(): Flow<UserModel?>
}
```

```
class UserRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(val userDataStore: UserDataStore): UserRepository {
    override suspend fun saveUser(userModel: UserModel) {
        userDataStore.putModel(userModel)
    }

    override suspend fun getUser(): Flow<UserModel?> {
        return userDataStore.getModel<UserModel>()
    }
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(val userRepository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
```

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(outputDirectory: File?) {
   val viewModel = hiltViewModel<HomeViewModel>()
```

or version with ViewModel from MainActivity

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(outputDirectory: File?, viewModel: HomeViewModel) {
```

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()
```

Modules:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApplication(@ApplicationContext app: Context): Application {
        return app as Application
    }
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DataStoresModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideUserDataStore(dataStoresProvider: DataStoresProvider): UserDataStore {
        return UserDataStore(dataStoresProvider)
    }

}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class UserModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideUserRepository(userDataStore: UserDataStore): UserRepository {
        return UserRepositoryImpl(userDataStore)
    }
}
```

My error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.insta.local.DataStoresProvider cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

I do not understand why it is not working. Every component provides another one till `viewModel`.

```
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements TransApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.example.instatrans.local.DataStoresProvider is injected at
          com.example.instatrans.module.DataStoresModule.provideUserDataStore(dataStoresProvider)
      com.example.instatrans.models.UserDataStore is injected at
          com.example.instatrans.module.UserModule.provideUserRepository(userDataStore)
      com.example.instatrans.repository.UserRepository is injected at
          com.example.instatrans.ui.home.HomeViewModel(userRepository)
      com.example.instatrans.ui.home.HomeViewModel is injected at
          com.example.instatrans.ui.home.HomeViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.example.instatrans.TransApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.example.instatrans.TransApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.example.instatrans.TransApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

UserDataStore

```
class UserDataStore @Inject constructor(
    val dataStoresProvider: DataStoresProvider
) : ModelDataStore<UserModel>(
    dataStoresProvider.userDataStore(),
    USER_KEY
) {

    companion object {
        val USER_KEY = baseStringPreferencesKey("USER_KEY")
    }
}
```

adding:

```
    @Provides
    fun provideUserDataStoreProvider(@ApplicationContext app: Context): DataStoresProvider {
        return DataStoreProviderImpl(app)
    }
```

with

````
class DataStoreProviderImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val context: Context
) : DataStoresProvider {

    private val Context.userDataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by appPreferencesDataStore(
        name = "userData"
    )

    override fun userDataStore(): DataStore<Preferences> {
        return context.userDataStore
    }

}

fun appPreferencesDataStore(name: String) = preferencesDataStore(name = name + DATA_STORE_SUFFIX)

private const val DATA_STORE_SUFFIX = "_v3"```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `DataStoresModule` to your `UserModule` because it is using a dependency (`UserDataStore`) from that module:

```kotlin
@Module(
    includes = [
        DataStoresModule::class
    ]
)
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class UserModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideUserRepository(userDataStore: UserDataStore): UserRepository {
        return UserRepositoryImpl(userDataStore)
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue:
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.insta.local.DataStoresProvider cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. Should I use the same mechanism somewhere with UserModule? Like inlcudes = [UserModule::class] In Edit entire error

Comment: If you are using any dependency from UserModule in another module, you should include it there.

Comment: I don't, I user just UserRepository directly as argument in  viewModel thats all

Comment: Can you share your implementation for `DataStoresProvider` interface?

Comment: added in thread

Comment: I think you misunderstood. It would be best if you had something like [this](https://github.com/atick-faisal/Jetpack-Compose-Starter/blob/main/storage/preferences/src/main/kotlin/dev/atick/storage/preferences/di/DatastoreModule.kt) to create the datastore. Right now, you only have an interface (DataStoresProvider) and not the implementation.

Comment: Dear god thank you that you send Atick Faisal to this world and I meet him in stackoverflow. Greetings, works as heaven! Comment in main thread